# Interpolate data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create some generic Terraform code which supports different MySQL version AMIs. AMIs of MySQL are not in my AWS account. They are in a different AWS account and shared with my account. I am using
a data source to get the latest MySQL AMIs from different account. Now I want to have some thing like this

```
terraform apply -var somevar=mysql5.6 (This should use mysql5.6 AMI for creating resources)
terraform apply -var somevar=mysql5.5 (This should use mysql5.5 AMI for creating resources)
```

But the problem is that I can't variablize/interpolate data source mentioned in resource section. Is there any other way to get what I am looking for?

This is the excerpt of what I tried till now

```
data "aws_ami" "mysql56" {
  owners = ["xxxxxxxxxxxx"]

  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "image-id"
    values = ["${var.os_to_ami["mysql56"]}"]
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "mysql55" {
  owners = ["xxxxxxxxxxxx"]

  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "image-id"
    values = ["${var.os_to_ami["mysql55"]}"]
  }
}
variable "os_to_ami" {
  type = "map"
  description = "OS to AMI mapping"
  default = {
        "mysql56" = "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        "mysql57" = "ami-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
ami            = "${data.aws_ami.mysql56}"
...
}
```

I am using Terraform v0.11.0.

Comment: Is there an error you're getting? If yes, would you mind posting the error also?

Comment: It sounds like you're quite new to Terraform. Is there a reason you're using such an old version of Terraform? It doesn't drastically change my answer but you should really be using at least 0.12+ for a ton of benefits including the new HCL2 syntax. If necessary you should explain why you are still on 0.11 and tag the question with `terraform0.11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data sources aren't doing anything useful because you're passing the AMI ID into them which defeats the point of them. Instead you should be using the `aws_ami` data source to fetch the AMI ID based on some criteria such as the owner and the name. This would then let you more simply look these up based on a variable.

Assuming the AMIs are being shared by account `123456789012` and have the names `mysql/mysql-5.5/20200818T212500Z` and `mysql/mysql-5.6/20200818T212500Z` then you'd do something like the following:

```
variable "mysql_version" {}

data "aws_ami" "mysql" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["mysql/mysql-${var.mysql_version}/*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["123456789012"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "mysql" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.mysql.id
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
}
```

With the above you have a required `mysql_version` variable that must be provided. This is then interpolated into the AMI name to search for and will return the latest one matching those criteria so if a new AMI was to be published by the `123456789012` account owner for the same MySQL version with a different timestamp then it would want to recreate your instance with that new AMI.

Comment: @ydaetskoR, it worked. Yes I am new to Terraform and I will be moving to newer version soon.